# Foreach not including string to the last checkbox

Tags: php, foreach

```
if(!empty($_POST['tenant'])) {   
    foreach($_POST['tenant'] as $check) {  
        if($tenant == '') {  
            $tenant =  $tenant . "" . $check;     
        } else {            
            $tenant =  $tenant . ":Y<br> " . $check;   
        }  
    }  
}
```

foreach loop not adding the :Y string to the last check box

Results is

Tenant Type:
Retail:Y
Government:Y
Distribution:Y
Student Housing
Articles: 1031 Exchange Strategies, 1031 Toolkit

Expected:

Tenant Type:
Retail:Y
Government:Y
Distribution:Y
Student Housing:Y
Articles: 1031 Exchange Strategies, 1031 Toolkit

Comment: Do you debug the values of array $_POST['tenant']?

Comment: Yes,it displays all checkbox value but the problem is string :Y is not concatenated in the last check box.just skipping off.

Comment: Add here var_dump($_POST['tenant']); thanks

Comment: Hi Legionar this is the result of var_dump `array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "Retail" [1]=> string(10) "Industrial" [2]=> string(7) "Medical" [3]=> string(6) "Office" }`

Comment: Hi, but your results is different (current and also expected). I dont see in your code "Tenant Type: ". Where is this adding to the string $tenant?

Comment: Actually its a email form, Tenant type is added in $message

Comment: Please, consider to edit your question, its not clear by now; var_dump is different, as your question. Comparing to var_dump, there are missing "Tenant Type:", "Government:", "Distribution:", "Student Housing Articles", "1031 Exchange Strategies, 1031 Toolkit"...

Comment: Could you also show us the lines in which you declare/initialise the variable `$tenant`?